# How is it possible to fill a OneToMany relationship with new entities in Symfony forms?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

I would like to create a form for my entity named `Order`:

```
/** @ORM\Entity */
class Order {
    //...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Entry::class, mappedBy="order", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $entries;
    //...
}
```

The `Entry` class looks like this:

```
/** @ORM\Entity */
class Entry {
    //...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Product::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $count = 0;
    //...
}
```

I already defined a type for `Entry`.

An `Order` has multiple `Entry`. I would like to make it possible to create the entries in the same form, where the `Order` is created. I can not use `EntityType` with `'multiple' => true`, because the `Entry` instances do not exist before the `Order`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CollectionType::class` to embed another form.
Create a `EntryType` form and add it to your `OrderType` form with a `CollectionType`field. Add a `allow_add` property and check the docs to find how to display the Form.

If you want to persist/flush all entities, you have to add a `cascade={'persist'} to your relation.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done by symfony using embedded form.

There are a lot to say about how to use it, so here are :

[Fully example step by step of how to do it from entity creation to html implementation](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/collections/embedded-form-collection)

[The symfony cookbook : **How to Embed a Collection of Forms**](https://symfony.com/doc/2.0//cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

[And symfony doc : How to Embed a Collection of Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)